# How can I add a third class to my classifier model depending on the probability of both classes?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, text-classification

I have a training dataset with two labels, positive and negative.

I want to add another class "neutral" depending on the prediction probabilities of positive and negative.

For example in MultinomialNB model, using the `predict_proba()` method I can access the probability estimates of each entry's prediction.

Like so:

```
[[0.18340814 0.81659186] 
 [0.14187741 0.85812259] 
 [0.42353162 0.57646838] 
 ...
 [0.82327649 0.17672351] 
 [0.1230776  0.8769224 ] 
 [0.22906    0.77094   ]]
```

Can I make it so that, when an entry's positive class probability is between 0.30 and 0.70, it should be classified as neutral instead of positive or negative?

Comment: You can do this, but it's unlikely to work well because the predicted probability can be completely wrong itself. For example you can have an instance predicted positive 99% which is actually negative. It's especially true with NB which tends to assign extreme probabilities very often.

Comment: Hmm, then I guess I'll refrain from doing that. I just wanted the entries with little to no information to not be classified as positive or negative.

Comment: You can try, it might work decently with your data, but don't expect too much from it.